# Alexa Slot Confirmation about AMAZON.DURATION slot type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, iso8601, alexa-slot

Recently, I'm building the Alexa skill with the built-in slot confirmation.
I found that when the slot type is AMAZON.DURATION, Alexa will confirm slot content with ISO-8601 duration format instead of verbal format.

For example, when the user says "10 mins", Alexa will reply with " Are you just said PT10M ?"  automatically. 
The Alexa Speech Prompt that I only set is in the Alexa develop console as 
"Are you just said {period}"

Is there any way can fix this or I can just set the question inside the Lambda function.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to convert this "PT10M" to "10 minutes" before Alexa confirms the slot?

Comment: Yes, and i found that I need to transform the type at the backend (AWS Lambda) by using slotConfirmation. It seems no way for us to transform the type by just setting in Alexa Developer Console

Answer (score 1):

For each turn in a conversation, your backend will receive a request from Alexa. The speech prompts that you have configured in Alexa console are used when you use `Delegate` directive of dialog model. ie, when you delegate the next step to Alexa.

When the user says "10 mins", you will receive a request in your backend. You have to validate the `{period}` slot and if it is valid convert it to "10 mins". You can do this by updating the slot value of `{period}` slot from "PT10M" to "10 mins" while delegating.